# laravel/installer v2.1.0 requires ext-zip - php-zip can not installing

Tags: laravel

I'm getting this error when installing laravel via composer

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^2.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v2.1.0].
    - laravel/installer v2.1.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/..
    ..
    ..   You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

there is no zip.ini file in /etc/php/7.3/cli

and I tried these;
apt-get install php-zip get this this result:

```
php-zip is already the newest version (1:7.0+49).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libglade2-0 net-tools php7.0-fpm python-glade2 python-gobject python-notify python-wicd
  rfkill wicd-daemon wicd-gtk
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

and

apt-get install php7.3-zip get this result:

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.3-zip
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3-zip'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3-zip'
```

I looked other topics but any of them dosen't work. How can i handle this problem

Comment: https://www.colinodell.com/blog/201812/how-install-php-73

Comment: thanks it worked! I noticed that the problem is my php repo